# React-Bootstrap: How to submit horizontal form?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have created a react-bootstrap traditional vertical form that works perfectly and gets submitted on-click like its designed to.

```
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, price, quantity } = this.state;

        const newItem = {
            name,
            price,
            quantity,
        };

        axios.post('/', newItem
        .then(
            (res) => {
                alert('Submitted successfully!');
                const clearState = {
                    name,
                    price,
                    quantity,
                };
                this.setState(clearState);
            },
            (err) => {
                alert('An error occured! Try submitting the form again.', err);
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                     <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={10}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="Text"
                      placeholder="name"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={10}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Enter cost of item"
                      name="price"
                      value={this.state.price}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={10}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Enter quantity"
                      name="quantity"
                      value={this.state.quantity}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Col smOffset={5} sm={4}>
                    <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, when I tried to change it to a Horizontal Form  by adding `Row` to the form wrapper like so :

`````
<div>
    <Form.Row horizontal onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

// rest of the code here

</Form.Row>

````

My submit button doesn't work, nothing happens, I know am doing something wrong but can't figure it out
`````

Comment: Why can't you just nest your `ROW` inside `FORM` i.e.

`<Form onSubmit={this.submit}> 
  <Row>
   // rest of code
  </Row>
</Form>`

Comment: Your suggestion solved it,thanks

Comment: Glad to know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form.Row` renders a div element with the class `form-row` - it is not a form element. That's why your submit doesn't work.

More info here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-row-props

Comment: @8SINS you can accept this as the answer if it answers your question, or ask for more information if you have additional questions.